# How to convert array of hashes into a single hash and count repeated items?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes, that I basically want to merge and convert to a single hash and at the same time I want to count the number of times a key:value pair occurs.

The original array is

```
cart_items = [
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true }},
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true }},
  {"KALE"    => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => false}}
]
```

I have tried this however I am not getting what I want. My attempt at this is below, if anyone could explain where I am going wrong, that would be great.

My attempt at this problem is this.

```
def consolidate_cart(items)
  ### the cart starts as an array of items
  ## convert the array into a hash`

 hashed_items = items.inject(:merge!)

 hashed_items.map{|k,v| {k => v, :count => v.length}}

end

consolidate_cart(cart_items)
```

I expect the output to be

```
{
  "AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true, :count => 2},
  "KALE"    => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => false, :count => 1}
}
```

But I get an output of

```
[{"AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true}, :count=>2}, {"KALE"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false}, :count=>2}]
```

Comment: `Hash#merge` loses information in this case. Try [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Comment: Also `v.length` in your snippet refers to the two key-value pairs in a hash `{:price => 3.0, :clearance => true }`. All hashes there have two elements, so you get 2 in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge to `v` (within the `map` call) the value of count (`v.merge(:count => v.length)`), so this will add the count key to the `v` hash, you'll get something like:

```
[
  {"AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :count=>2},
  {"KALE"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :count=>2}
]
```

But anyways the values for `:count` are going to be wrong.

In the other hand, you can get all the keys from each hash in cart_items, merge the hashes, and then merge a new key with the count of that key in the stored keys array:

```
def consolidate_cart(items)
  items_keys = items.flat_map(&:keys)
  items.inject(:merge).map do |key, value|
    { key => value.merge(count: items_keys.count(key)) }
  end
end

p consolidate_cart(cart_items)
# [{"AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :count=>2}}, {"KALE"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :count=>1}}]
```

---

A part by part view of the method functioning:

You map the keys of each hash item (`items.flat_map(&:keys)`):

```
["AVOCADO", "AVOCADO", "KALE"]
```

You merge the hash within `items` (`items.inject(:merge)`):

```
{"AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true}, "KALE"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false}}
```

When you iterate over the previous generated hash, you merge to each hash value the count key (`{ key => value.merge(count: items_keys.count(key)) }`):

```
# {:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true}
# {:count=>2}
# => {:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :count => 2}
```

---

I've already seen my answer doesn't correspond with the expected output. This does:

```
def consolidate_cart(items)
  items.inject(:merge).each_with_object(items: items.flat_map(&:keys)) do |(k, v), hash|
    hash[k] = v.merge(count: hash[:items].count(k))
  end.reject { |k, _| k == :items }
end
```

Comment: could you explain what each part of your code does please?

Comment: I've added something to explain that @ZubairMaqsood

Comment: This has the disadvantage that `count` is executed for each key (computational complexity (`O(n**2)`), whereas those counts can be obtained by making a single pass through those keys (`O(n)`).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a way to consider also the case where `price` or `clearance` of the same product (`String`) can be different (since you are not dealing with database ids):

```
cart_items = [
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true }},
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 4.0, :clearance => false }},
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true }},
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 4.0, :clearance => true }},
  {"KALE"    => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => false}},
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 4.0, :clearance => true }},
  {"AVOCADO" => {:price => 4.0, :clearance => true }}
]
```

In this case this is a possible way to consolidate:

```
cart_items.map{ |h| h.values.first.merge(product: h.keys.first) }
  .group_by(&:itself)
  .transform_values { |v| v.first.merge(count: v.size)}.values
```

It is returning:

```
#=> [{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :product=>"AVOCADO", :count=>2}, {:price=>4.0, :clearance=>false, :product=>"AVOCADO", :count=>1}, {:price=>4.0, :clearance=>true, :product=>"AVOCADO", :count=>3}, {:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :product=>"KALE", :count=>1}]
```

---

You can always append `.group_by{ |h| h[:product] }` to get

```
#=> {"AVOCADO"=>[{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :product=>"AVOCADO", :count=>2}, {:price=>4.0, :clearance=>false, :product=>"AVOCADO", :count=>1}, {:price=>4.0, :clearance=>true, :product=>"AVOCADO", :count=>3}], "KALE"=>[{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :product=>"KALE", :count=>1}]}
```

Or for the cart in your post:

```
#=> {"AVOCADO"=>[{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :product=>"AVOCADO", :count=>2}], "KALE"=>[{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :product=>"KALE", :count=>1}]}
```

Not exactly the same output as required, but maybe this can be useful. Or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
cart_items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g] += 1 }.
  map { |g,cnt| { g.keys.first=>g.values.first.merge(count: cnt) } }

  #=> [{"AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :count=>2}},
  #    {"KALE"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :count=>1}}]
```

`Hash.new(0)` is sometimes called a *counting hash*. See the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument equal to the hash's *default value*. We obtain:

```
cart_items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g] += 1 }
  #=> {{"AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true}}=>2,
  #    {"KALE"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false}}=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cart_items.group_by(&:itself).map{ |item, group| item[item.keys.first][:count] = group.size; item}
```

For demo https://rextester.com/MFH44079